# Android: How to create slide (on/off) button

Tags: android, button, slider, switch-statement, slide

I'd like to create a slide button (= something as switch ) with two states: on and off so user will have to press the button and slide it to change the state (something similar as unlock slider but not cross whole screen). Do you have any idea how to do it? I really tried to find the answer but I haven't been successful.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds  like the [`Switch` control](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html). That's new in Ice Cream Sandwich *(Android 4.0)*, so you are not able to use it in older versions. But since the source was released yesterday or so afaik you can have a look into it and see how it's done. Apart from that have a look at [custom components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).

Comment: You can use Toggle button for 2 states(On and OFF)

Comment: 4sat- but Toggle button doesn't support move I think. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I have put a version of the Switch widget that works on Android 2.2 here: https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well it seems that [Switch component](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) is the best solution if your target SDK is higher than 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich). So for the others who will face the same problem look at it. :)

Answer (score 11):

//in your layout design the below line

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rl_onoff"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/on_btn" android:layout_width="80dp"  android:layout_height="40dp" android:src="@drawable/on_btn" android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/off_btn" android:layout_width="80dp"  android:layout_height="40dp" android:src="@drawable/off_btn" android:visibility="invisible"></ImageView>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

// in your activity call this

```
ImageView mNotification_on_btn=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.on_btn);
ImageView mNotification_off_btn=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.off_btn);

    mNotification_on_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mNotification_on_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mNotification_off_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    mNotification_off_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mNotification_off_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mNotification_on_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

// this will switch like iphone style on off toggle button[image]
[image]

Comment: this will not have the "transition", it doesn't slide between two states. Besides, it's a good option!

Comment: Thank you very much but as has been noticed I need the transition between two states. I found some video on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ImHe4N4mvE4#t=8s3) but I cannot find the code :(

Comment: I guess, its better to use Toggle Button then using two ImageViews and showing / hiding them in code. Anyways both don't have sliding transition.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by use check box or ToggleButton. Below is an example

xml file

```
 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_on_of"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/chec_box_on_off"
       />
```

drawable chec_box_on_off file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_box_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_box_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

you will get like on off button and also you can check whether checkbox is on or off.

the java code is

```
 CheckBox check = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_on_of);
 check.isChecked();
```

Similarly, you can also achieve this using ToggleButton.