# i need the ON/OFF button for enable/disable by clicking the button ,this is possible by using OnClickListner or any method?

Tags: android, button, android-layout, coding-style, android-manifest

how to do the button with ON/Off by clicking it must varies and along with that it shows Green for ON else RED. this is possible without graphics or must need graphics?
any one tried like this plz help me?

Comment: try with your graphics http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150596/android-how-to-create-slide-on-off-button/8151252#8151252

Comment: yaa......but im getting error like:: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Answer (score 3):

[ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) does the same. And here is [tutorial](http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/android-togglebutton-example/) which will tell how to use this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html)

If you with to use Button instead, you can make field `boolean m_isOn;` in your class, and in OnClickListener check this field and set button color (e.g. with setColorFilter()) and text accordingly.

**Edit**

Small example, if you really wish to avoid ToggleButton and using drawables:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    m_isOn ^= true;
    ((Button)v).getBackground().setColorFilter(m_isOn ? 0xFF00FF00 : 0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    ((Button)v).setText(m_isOn ? "ON" : "OFF");
}
```

Comment: yep.......im getting error like Description Resource Path Location Type
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 onOffbutton  Unknown Android Packaging Problem

Comment: something must be wrong with your project properties or imports then. try googling error description, it seems to give couple of solutions

Comment: here im getting error like:: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Answer (score 0):

use ImageButton instead of button, and selector as image.
this XML file you can put into drawable directory

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true"
         android:drawable="@drawable/button_prev_active" /> 
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_prev_no_active" />
```

In layout do this:

```
 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnPrev" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY" 
        android:padding="0px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:onClick="prevClickHandler"
        android:src="@drawable/button_prev_selector"/>
```