# How to implement sliding button?

Tags: android, android-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to create slide (on/off) button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150596/android-how-to-create-slide-on-off-button)

I want to create sliding button in my Android application such that it will look like the following:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Please see Below links for make custom toggle button. [Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938315/toggle-button-in-iphone-style) [Link 2](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/07/sexily-styled-toggle-buttons-for-android/)

Comment: Update: [**Switch widget**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) is also there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) for creating this  sliding button

see this tutorial for Creating Custom ToggleButton in Android

[Sexily Styled Toggle Buttons for Android](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/07/sexily-styled-toggle-buttons-for-android/) ([archive.org mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20150324115134/http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/07/sexily-styled-toggle-buttons-for-android/))

**EDIT :** if you are using Android API LEVEL 14 or above then you can also use [Switch Widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) for creating sliding button see this example :

[Creating a Switch](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Introduction_to_Ice_Cream_Sandwich)

Comment: What about to use [`Switch Widget`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html)?

Comment: Switch Widget added in Android API Level 14. and i'm not getting any working example.

Comment: Yup..i am working on 4.0.3.Thanks paresh and imaran for help.. it works